# How to get the names of the most expensive SPs in SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server

With the following query I get the list of top 10 most expensive queries with their SQL statements.

```
select top 10 * 
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
order by max_logical_reads desc
```

But how can I extract their object names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the last column "text" for me on SQL Server 2005 SP3, like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProc @parameter 1 int...
```

You could try `OBJECT_NAME(objectid)` but [Metadata Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113%28SQL.90%29.aspx) may prevent this (like it does me on my production boxes)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with persisent objects (i.e. stored procedures) then you can join on `sysobjects` like this:

```
select top 10 o.name from sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) b 
inner join sys.sysobjects o on b.objectid = o.id
order by max_logical_reads desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 10 OBJECT_NAME(objectid), * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
order by max_logical_reads desc
```

Answer (score 0):

automaticaly you can't. you'll have to parse them out yourself from the [Text] column